# Capybara is finding elements that would not be visible to the user

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, capybara, rspec-rails

I'm creating RSpec feature tests using capybara, for testing that uses Bootstrap tabs.

My problem is that even without using `click_link "tab name"` capybara is still able to find the elements that are located within that tab. However, when looking at the page in my local server, the tabs are functioning correctly.

How exactly does capybara find elements? Does it somehow use a system that bypasses the bootstraped tabs?

Is there any way to fix this?

**Possible factors involved:**

- For various reasons, the project that I'm working on is calling these "request" tests rather than feature tests. Could this be changing some of the behavior of capybara?

**Update**:
 - I currently do not have `js: true` set. Looking into that possible solution now.

Comment: If you're not using a JS capable driver then you'd be using the default rack-test driver. That driver doesn't process most CSS, which coupled with no JS support means bootstraps tab won't function at all

Comment: and, yes - when using Capybara it should be a 'feature' spec rather than a 'request' spec, especially if you're using the normal `require 'capybara/rspec`  -  Marking it a feature test should prevent you from using the `get`/``post`/etc methods which aren't compatible with using Capybara at the same time.

Comment: @ThomasWalpole , thanks, this is helpful. The leader of the project wants me to leave as much alone as possible, however. Is it absolutely necessary to change to feature specs, or is it just highly recommend it? You know what actually starts breaking down when using request specs rather than feature specs?

Comment: It just protects you from some common beginner mistakes, and you have to manually include the capybara dsl into request specs to use them there.  It's easy enough to just add type: :feature metadata to a specific test though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this behavior is that :js was set to false, and accordingly capybara was defaulting to using a rack-based driver. This driver doesn't process most CSS, and CSS plus no JavaScript support means that the bootstrap tabs would not function. Accordingly, each of the tabs would basically be viewable and selectable all at the same time, whether or not any of the tab links were clicked. This meant that it was still possible to click those links, but that it did not do anything.

Credit goes to @ThomasWalpole (see the comments)